# Regex #ifdef with empty lines

Tags: regex

I've this patterns in my code:

```
#ifdef A

printf("a");
// hello

// comment

#endif
```

This is the desired result:

```
\n (should be empty line)
printf("a");
// hello

// comment
\n (should be empty line)
```

Removing the line with #ifdef or #endif but don't touch any other lines - including empty lines.

This is my current regex -

```
(?:#ifdef\s*(?:\w+)\n(?P<text>(?:(?:[\s\S]*?)*?))\n[\s]*#endif)
```

But it doesn't capture the last empty lines.

What can I do? Thanks!
*using python regex

Comment: Do you mean `\n`?

Comment: Why did the second `// hello` change to `// comment`?

Comment: my bad, it should be //comment on both

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -v` to remove lines matching a regular expression.

```
grep -E -v '#ifdef|#endif' filename > filename.new
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: you do not specify, but you appear to be using features of a Perl-compatible regex language, such as Perl's own, Java's, or PCRE.  My suggested regex and its explanation rely on that choice of language.

---

Your pattern explicitly matches the newline at the end of the `#ifdef` line and *at least* one preceding the `#endif` line.  Note also, however, that `\s` matches newlines.  Thus, the newline(s) immediately preceding the `#endif` line are (all) outside the boundary of your capture group:

```
                   +---- newlines ---------------+...
                   |                             |  :
                   V                             V  v
(?:#ifdef\s*(?:\w+)\n(?P<text>(?:(?:[\s\S]*?)*?))\n[\s]*#endif)
                     ^                          ^
                     |                          |
                     +-- capture boundaries  ---+
```

A regular expression with the capture semantics seem to want might be

```
(?ms:^\h*#ifdef.*?^(?P<text>.*?)^\h*#endif.*?$.?)
```

Explanation:

- The multiline flag is ensured on for a non-capturing group surrounding the rest of the pattern (`(?m`) so that `^` and `$` match just after and just before *any* line break, respectively, not just at the beginning and end of the input.
- The dotall flag is also ensured on (`s:`) so that the `.` metacharacter matches newlines.
- The `\h` escape matches "horizontal" whitespace characters, which include spaces and tabs but not newlines.  Thus `\h*#ifdef` and `\h*#endif` match the directives even if they are preceeded by (horizontal) whitespace on the same line, but they exclude any preceding newlines.
- With the use of a lazy quantifier and multiline, the pattern fragment `.*?^` matches everything up to and including the next newline, regardless of the dotall flag.  With this, the newline at the end of the `ifdef` line is excluded from the capture group, as in the original regex.
- With dotall mode in effect and the use of a lazy quantifier, the pattern `(?P<text>.*?)` matches the minimal run of arbitrary characters necessary for the pattern tail, `^\h*#endif.*?$.?`, to match.
- with multiline mode enabled and use of a lazy quantifier, that tail matches a whole single line, starting *after* a preceding newline and including the line's own newline, if any, provided that the line starts with zero or more horizontal whitespace characters followed by "#endif".

The resulting capture group named "text" contain the text you want.

---

Final note: some online regex testers on which I tried the suggested regex seemed to disagree with me about whether the newlines preceding the `#endif` should be included in the captured group, but I think that's a display issue.  The following C program can be used to demonstrate that PCRE, at least, does capture those newlines in the first ("text") capture group:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcre.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *error;
    int err_offset;
    int input_length = 0;
    int vector[33] = {0};
    pcre *pattern = pcre_compile(
            "(?ms:^\\h*#ifdef.*?^(?P<text>.*?)^\\h*#endif.*?$.?)",
            0, &error, &err_offset, NULL);
    char buffer[4096];

    scanf("%4095[\001-\377]%n", buffer, &input_length);

    int result = pcre_exec(pattern, NULL, buffer, input_length, 0, 0, vector, 33);
    printf("Full match:\n%.*s\n", vector[1] - vector[0], buffer + vector[0]);
    printf("\nCaptured group:\n%.*s\n", vector[3] - vector[2], buffer + vector[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm using python so this worked:
re.compile(r"(?:^[ \t]*#ifdef.*?^(?P<text>.*?)^[ \t]*#endif.*?$.?)",flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)